# How to print pdf from window.print() using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, internet-explorer, firefox

I am opening new window in that passing pdfurl. when i click print pdf, pdf document will open very nicely in new window. but when i do, newwindowInstance.print(); it is throughs error like this **TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'win.print()')**. Below i have given code. Can any one tell me. how to resolve this issue. How print pdf from window print? Great appropriated. Thank you.

**Code Here:**

```
var win = window.open(speficationUrl, name);       
        setTimeout(function() {
            win.print();
            win.close();
        }, 5000);
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687675/can-a-pdf-files-print-dialog-be-opened-with-javascript

Comment: I have above link,But it is giving different error like  Domains, protocols and ports must match.
VesselPrintController.js:134TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'getMyFrame.contentWindow.print()')
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.gulfmark.com/_filelib/FileCabinet/pdfs/Enea.pdf from frame with URL file:///E:/GulfMark/trunk/Source/index.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
VesselPrintController.js:134TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'getMyFrame.contentWindow.print()'). code is Below.

Comment: var getMyFrame = document.getElementById('iframeId');
        getMyFrame.focus();
        getMyFrame.contentWindow.print();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open PDF in a new window, print that PDF and Close the window. How to do this in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970318/open-pdf-in-a-new-window-print-that-pdf-and-close-the-window-how-to-do-this-in)